# Efficient way to convert a df to a dictionary with one column as keys and values which are dictionary containing two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dictionary

I have a df

```
    A      B    C
0   NAME1  11   x
1   NAME2  22   y
2   NAME3  33   z
```

and I want to get a dictionary which has column A as keys and values which are a dictionary containing columns B and C (with column names as keys of that dictionary) like:

```
{"NAME1": {"B": 11, "C": x}, "NAME2": {"B": 22, "C": y}, "NAME3": {"B": 33, "C": z}}
```

Currently I am doing this with `df.set_index("A").to_dict("index")` but I am concerned about the performance of set_index on a large dataset. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Been looking into this some more and `dict(zip(df.A, (df[["B","C"]].to_dict("records"))))` seems to be slightly more efficient.

Comment: Just a thought, could you set your index when you create the df object rather than when you're converting to a dictionary?